# Why can't a closed ClientWebSocket be reopened without a creating a new instance of the ClientWebSocket?

Tags: c#, websocket, system.net.websockets

I'm currently working on a `System.Net.WebSockets` implementation that will be using cellular networks to send data packets about the device in a real-time manner. Using cellular network means that my solution should be able to reconnect a socket when the network occasionally loses connection. The only way that I have been able to do this is by creating a new instance of the `ClientWebSocket` and then sending the connect message asynchronously.

This is not my exact code but hopefully it will get the idea across of what I am trying to do.

```cs
void PublisherConnect()
        {
            myWebSocket = new ClientWebSocket();    
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {        
                if (myWebSocket.ConnectionState != WebSocketState.Open)
                {                
                    try
                    {
                        await myWebSocket.ConnectAsync(HostString);
                    }
                    catch (WebSocketException ee)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(ee.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

```cs
internal async Task ConnectAsync(Uri uri)
        {            
            using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
            {
                try
                {                    
                    await myWebSocket.ConnectAsync(uri, CancellationToken.None);
                    manualState = false;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

If I try to connect again with the same object after a clean disconnect, an error is thrown with the message, "The websocket has already been started." What is it about WebSockets that I don't understand?

EDIT - I am building this into a NuGet package to be used as a library for other apps so I need to stay around .NET 4.6 due to how the programs that will be consuming this function.

Comment: Once disconnected, a socket *must* be closed. This is the nature of TCP/IP sockets, which WebSockets are built on. In your case, I'd see if I could get a SignalR client working, since it handles reconnections automatically for you.

Comment: @StephenCleary I added an edit explaining (hopefully adequately) why I can't use SignalR. You did give me the idea to look at how SignalR is handling reconnecting though so thank you.

Comment: OK. You will have to handle the close-and-reconnect logic yourself, then. :/  Closing the socket and constructing and connecting a new one is the appropriate way to handle this.

Comment: This is just how those classes were implemented. They *could've* been implemented in a way where you could close and reopen them any number of times, but they weren't. So once closed, if you want to reopen, throw away the old object and construct a new one.